# Can't push bazaar repository into git using dpush

Tags: git, github, merge, bazaar, dhis-2

I am not able to push a bazaar repository into Git.
I have used this command :

> bzr dpush git+ssh://git@github.com/harsh-a1/dhis_2.22.git,branch=master

Am getting the following error:

> bzr: ERROR: The file id "None" is not present in the tree   bzrlib.inventory.CHKInventory object at 0x7f3613337290

I want to see how git merges are different from bazaar ones....am fed up of merging with bazaar so giving this a try.
Found the above method on internet for linking bazaar to github but not working....Is there any hope?

Answer (score 0):

We have migrated the source code to https://github.com/dhis2/dhis2-core, so you should be able to use git directly now.